# Prevent user from browsing internet

Tags: java, web

I am trying to make an online application that will be like an online exam, But I want to ensure that no user can browse internet during the test. Is it possible ANYHOW? 
I am thinking about a fullscreen application that don't minimize. But that cannot eliminate the chances that user alt-tabs other window :(

Any direction is highly appreciated.

Technology is no bar.  Having said that, the students will be ***taking the test from home***.

Comment: Please mention the platform: Windows or others and technology you are familiar with: windows system administration and programming and stuff

Comment: If you really want to do this in Java (according to the tag), the answer is simple. No, not possible

Comment: @aitchnyu: I am hoping for a cross platform solution that is why I added the java tag, but even if it's windows specific it will work great for me.

Comment: *"But I want to ensure that no user can browse internet during the test."* So your saying I can't use my new net enabled phone?  Too bad.  BTW - what is the relevance of a 'closed book'(/'no net') exam in this day & age?  Are you testing people for 'Survivor' or a tour of duty at an Antarctic base?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Hahah :D M sorry you will need to wait till the exam is over to browse your fav sites on your phone :)

Comment: BTW - please leave noise like 'Thanks' & sigs. out of posts.  That sort of stuff should go on [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1234007/aman-gautam), if it is that important to you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the phone.  Please also enlighten me about the 'relevance'.  This is something that interests me very much.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I want user to come to my site and use it, but not use any other website for 3 hours. One answer I got is, to do it using firewall, which is infact amazing but is harder to implement as students will be taking exams from home :)

Comment: *"students will be taking exams from home"*  So even if you can stop me browsing around in FF, what makes you think I will not then just open IE, or Opera, or Chrome, or use my phone?  This is important information that should be ***edited into the question***, rather than being 'buried' in a comment.  (And I think it kills any chance of achieving this.  Most people would be assuming you control the network, machine or browser, whereas it seems that is all out of your control.)

Comment: You can't do it. Period. Even if you manage to somehow block internet access on that computer (which I seriously doubt), the student can easily use another computer to go online. Having more than 1 computer these days is not so uncommon (they're really cheap).

Comment: How about having someone sitting next to you, helping you? This is not internet, this is even better - no keyboard and no lag.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be better solved on the network layer in your school router. 
Block IP access to everything except the online test for this class room while test is being taken..

Comment: This is amazing. But I wonder how can I do it if user is taking test from home and not from college?

Answer (score 2):

> Technology is no bar. Having said that, the students will be **taking
>   the test from home**.

Do understand the spirit of  laws 1,2,3 of the [10 Immutable Laws of Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722487.aspx):

> Law #1: If a bad guy can persuade you to run his program on your
>   computer, it's not your computer anymore
>   Law #2: If a bad guy can
>   alter the operating system on your computer, it's not your computer
>   anymore
>   Law #3: If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your
>   computer, it's not your computer anymore

**The only computers that conform to your will (in your case, you want the PCs to disallow browsing) are those for which you have complete control of the hardware and software.**

You can fool only the less sophisticated users. If your users are inclined, they can easily learn to bust it. From the DRM fiasco and certain personal anecdotes from school and college, its well proven that the users can be **one step ahead** and trying to close the gap is a **black hole for money and effort**.

---

Also the kids are at home. They can always use other devices or means. You can make a page with javascript that can prevent it from going out of focus, but a 10 year old can learn to open another window. Make a fullscreen desktop app that  checks if the mouse is "inside" , a 16 year old can run it on a virtual machine or screen session. Yes, I was that smart at that age and kids are getting more smarter than you or me.

Also, automated systems to detect wrongdoing are likely to **take innocent victims** and cause pain and resentment. Internet filters that [trip on](http://www.pluggd.in/indian-it-companies-firewall-blocks-steve-jobs-death-297/) "Steve **Jobs** death" and "new c# **jobs**" for the same reason are an annoyance. Payment processors and site advertising with automated fraud detection algorithms and customer care that stonewalls have made people broke.

Comment: I would add one more thing, kids are even smarter, they will use their smartphones while taking your test on their computers... Period, can't block that... Ever...

Answer (score 1):

You could also set a system (IE) proxy, and write a small Proxy Server to intercept any outbound requests and return nothing
Writing such  Proxy is trivial...
If you are on Windows, you could write a batch file to start your program and use the REG command to modify the registry key(s)

Comment: Would have helped if the original had mentioned taking the test from home... In that case there is NO possible way to do what you want, as they can easily have a laptop and 3G modem sitting right next to them to  - and as Vincent says... 'From Home' is hardly a test... (maybe useful for like, 1% mini-tests and the like though) - You also might want to look into WebCT -does all this sort of stuff although not sure if Java is related to it or not

Comment: Edit: Sorry, WebCT is commercial